# Java Swing moving java.awt.Shape

Tags: java, swing, drawing, java-2d

We have an application that displays a kind of map. This Swing application mainly draw a set of [`java.awt.Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)s with [`java.awt.Graphics2D#draw(Shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) and everything is fine.

And now, I have to extend this app to allow our users editing (moving shapes on) the map. But there is no `translate` or `move` methods on `java.awt.Shape`s. So I can't change the position (`java.awt.Point`) of a shape.

I have tried to override [`java.awt.Shape#getPathIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#getPathIterator(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform)) in order to apply a translation that matches the shape position. But It's tricky because this method already accept a transformation that I have to merge and also because to be correct the `PathIterator` should then start at `(0, 0)` because it is relative to the shape position.

And anyway, that won't work because it seems that `Graphics2D` don't always use this method to draw a `java.awt.Shape`.

So now, I'm feeling a bit lost. Another solution could be to let shapes drawn themselves, but then I have to rewrite a part of the application. That's not a problem but I have to know which could be the best solution :

1. **Find a trick to *move* a `java.awt.Shape`**
   Seems to be the best solution but I can't figure how to do that.
2. **Change the app to have self drawing shapes**
   Could be nice but then I have to compute myslef the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains(double,%20double)) and other more complex methods.

Comment: Did you check AffineTransform?

Comment: Either translate the `Graphics` context your using to paint the `Shape` (using a `AffineTransform`) or use a `AffineTransform` to translate the shape using it's `createTransformedShape` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But there is no `translate` or `move` methods on `java.awt.Shape`s.

See [`AffineTransform.createTransformedShape(Shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-), which:

> Returns a new `Shape` object defined by the geometry of the specified `Shape` after it has been transformed by this transform.

Of course, there is also [`Graphics2D.translate(x,y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate-int-int-) ..

> Translates the origin of the `Graphics2D` context to the point (x, y) in the current coordinate system. ..

Comment: Thanks. `GraphicsD.translate(x, y)` won't work because the path of a shape is absolute. Thus if I translate and draw, then the shape should be missplaced.

Comment: *"`GraphicsD.translate(x, y)` won't work.."*  Of course it will!  But using `createTransformedShape(Shape)` is easier, since you don't need to reset the `Graphics2D` to the origin between drawing each shape.

Answer (score 4):

You can create Area based on your Shape and call transform() passing AffineTransform with translated coordinates.

```
Area a=new Area(sourceShape);
AffineTransform at=new AffineTransform();
at.translate(horizontalShift, verticalShift);
Shape transformedShape=a.transform(at);
```

Haven't tested though

Comment: `AffineTransform` has a `createTransformedShape` method, which returns a `Shape`, which is infinitely easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewThompson's solution seems to be the best one. And I'm going to give it a try.

For those interested (Because I had to progress). I have created one interface who extends `java.awt.Shape` and has a setter for his *location* property.
Each specific shape has to implement the code needed to update his location but it is much easier than having to move any kind of shape.